# Rails CSV import not functioning properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, csv, import

Basically, CSV import doesn't work.

Model Code:

```
def self.import(file,admin_id)
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    new_row = row.to_hash.merge(:merchant_id => admin_id)    
    Inventory.create! new_row 
  end
end

def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
require 'iconv'
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
        when ".csv" then Roo::Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
        when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
        when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
        else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
end
```

Controller action:

```
def import
  Inventory.import(params[:file],params[:admin_id])
  redirect_to :inventories, :notice => "Imported Successfully."
end
```

Import button, select file, all that working fine.  On submit:

> ```
>     SyntaxError in InventoriesController#import
>
>     (eval):2: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
>                     read_key(:Parts name)
>                                         ^
>     (eval):6: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
>                     read_key_before_type_cast(:Parts name)
>                                                          ^
>     (eval):10: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
>                     write_key(:Parts name, value)
>                                          ^
>     (eval):10: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '='
>     (eval):14: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
>                     read_key(:Parts name).present?
>                                         ^
>     (eval):15: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
> ```

Can someone please shed some light on this?  I can't even find a good way to debug the actual method to see exactly what it tries to do and how it fails on.

There is a template CSV file that looks like this across the header row:

> Parts name    Parts
>   number    Quantity    Cost    Price   Tax Location    Description Is editable

Comment: This seems like a bug in MongoMapper, try to update the gem.

Comment: I haven't looked at the CSV-processing gem, but it sure appears like it assumes that the column names in the CSV template are valid symbol strings and the presence of the spaces in "Parts name" and "Parts number" is causing the syntax error.

Comment: @Peter - Taking the spaces out moved us forward a step.  It's still failing, but not complaining about the Parts Name stuff any longer.  Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment, the syntax errors arise from trying to turn the column names into symbols, which doesn't work if the column names contain spaces. The offending code appears to be in https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/blob/f5f695215effea909df65304898f4512600baa08/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/keys.rb, but I didn't check to see if there is documentation or an issue relating to this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be the spaces in the header names.  I wish Peter would submit the answer so I can click it